# row.names in structure() function

Tags: r

I have a question in the row.names argument in the `structure()` function.
  Trying to construct a data.frame by the following code:

```
x <- structure(class = "data.frame", list( foo = c("foo1", "foo2"), bar = c(23, 45)))
```

However when I print `x` it says:

```
> x
[1] foo bar
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It's only when I have specified `row.names` that the data content gets pushed in:

```
> x <- structure(class = "data.frame", list( foo = 1, bar = "barcode"), 
                 .Names = c("foo", "bar"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

> x
  foo     bar   
1   1 barcode
```

Can someone please explain the `row.names` significance in the `structure()` function?

Comment: Row names are part of the definition, from `?data.frame`: "A data frame is a list of variables of the same number of rows with unique row names, given class 'data.frame'." Really, you should construct data frames with the `data.frame` function (or variants), though; `structure` is much lower-level.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It makes sense!